# Akamai edge-config XML specification

Tags: cdn, akamai

Per the title, I'm looking for Akamai edge-config XML specification. Using the "Property Manager" is not available presently to me. I do not need the API/JSON specification, nor the W3C ESI spec, but the XML config doc spec.

`<akamai:edge-config version="5.0">`

All of my searches turn up the API but not the actual XML spec

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot modify the xml metadata directly, only akamai employees are allowed to do that so there is no public domain (or customer/partner for that matter) documentation available